# Adjust data within bubble of chat page

Tags: android, xml, listview

On setting text within bubble of listview in chatpage, the data comes out of the bubble. How can we adjust it so that it remains within the bubble?

Here is xml for rowlayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5sp"
        android:background="@drawable/bubblenormal"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1" 
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I can't post image because of being new user.

Comment: set image to your main layout.. or use 9 patch image for bubble...

Comment: can you please provide any link for doing so? and please elaborate on setting image to main layout

Comment: you are setting background for Textview instead of this.. try to set it as LinearLayout's BG

Answer (score 0):

Follow [**This Link**](http://javapapers.com/android/android-chat-bubble/) To Create Bubble Chat Screen............

and use [**9-patch image**](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) like below image for sample...

[image]

Comment: in example you provided they also used :<TextView
            android:id="@+id/singleMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:background="@drawable/bubble_b"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:text="Hello bubbles!"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light" />

Answer (score 0):

try this ,

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/contentBody_left"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/chatleft" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chat_compact_message_left"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/contentBody_right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/chatright" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chat_compact_message_right"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

use this in adapter to hide your view's or holder's based on incoming chat or outgoing chat msg

```
        if(incoming){
        holder.contentBody_right.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.contentBody_left.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
         holder.contentBody_right.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.contentBody_left.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       }
```

Comment: The app doesnt responds.
logcat:
    07-30 04:23:45.760: E/AndroidRuntime(904): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    07-30 04:23:45.760: E/AndroidRuntime(904): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.classes.chatpage}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText

Comment: its clearly gives java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText, in xml its TextView ,use TextView also in Activity or Java code not EditText..